# How to use :nth-child pseudo-class to change color of tiles on odd rows

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm building a UI where I have to display 2 tiles on a single row. What I'm trying to achieve is to have the color of tiles on odd numbered rows be changed.
This is what I'm doing:

```
div.tile:nth-child(odd),button.btn-odd:nth-child(n)
{
  background: rgba(26, 188, 156,1.0);
  border-color: rgba(26, 188, 156,1.0);
}

div.tile:nth-child(odd):hover,button.btn-odd:nth-child(n):hover,div.tile:nth-child(odd):hover .btn-odd 
{
    background: rgba(22, 160, 133,1.0);
    border-color: rgba(22, 160, 133,1.0)
}       
button.btn-odd:nth-child(n):focus
{
    background: rgba(22, 160, 133,1.0);
    border-color: rgba(22, 160, 133,1.0)    
}
button.btn-odd:nth-child(n):active
{
    background: rgba(22, 160, 133,1.0);
    border-color: rgba(22, 160, 133,1.0)    
}
```

For more information, check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZC43W/  [stretch it out to see 2 tiles on a row]
Now the problem is that the tiles on the first row are giving me the required effect. However, tiles on the 2nd row (even row) are also exhibiting the same effect (green color although they should be blue). Can anyone tell me why this is happening? It seems that the nth-child selector is selecting all the rows instead of only odd numbered rows.

Comment: You have a few occurrences `:nth-child(n)` in your CSS - this is a guaranteed match on *any* child element.

Comment: That was basically to select all the buttons on a row on an odd numbered tile. But yes, it could be done in a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should actually use these as selector...

```
div.row:nth-child(odd) div.tile
div.row:nth-child(odd) div.tile .btn-odd
div.row:nth-child(odd) div.tile:hover
div.row:nth-child(odd) div.tile:hover .btn-odd
```

... and so on, as you want the effect to kick in based on the row's (and that's `div.row`) index.

As it stands now, the selector covers all the elements - as each `div.tile` is actually a single child of `div.col-md-6` element. And 1 is an odd number, right. )

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AE3VV/).

As a sidenote, using `:nth-child(n)` is plain redundant (it'll be applied to *any* element covered by the preceding selector). Unless you really need to upper the specificity of the selector - but then again, there are better ways to achieve this.

Comment: Your suggestion is correct, but according to NoN01's JSFiddle, it won't work because of the <br> tags. :nth-child considers all direct children of the parent when numbering. On the other hand NoN01 should not need the <br> tags at all. He should be using margins instead.

Comment: @dzny Let me guess - you haven't checked the fiddle, have you? ) It works, as there's no `<br />` between *outer* rows. But you're correct, of course, about margins.

Comment: Right, I understand now what I was doing wrong. Thanks alot!
And yes, I was basically using :nth-child(n) to select all the odd tile buttons. But like you said, there are better ways to achieve it.